# Exception: Matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to generate a token for users requesting for forget password. I have a model to handle and store this.

**models.py**

```
class ForgetPassword(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    forget_password_token = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

The view functions that handles the request are below

**views.py**

```
def forget_password(request):

    try:

        if request.method == 'POST':
            user_email = request.POST.get('email')

            if CustomUser.objects.filter(email = user_email).exists():
                
                user_obj = CustomUser.objects.get(email = user_email)

                name = user_obj.full_name
                plan = user_obj.plan

                print("\n this is the user : ", user_obj, " this is its name : ", name,"\n")

                token = str(uuid.uuid4())
                
                fp = ForgetPassword.objects.get(user = user_obj)
                fp.forget_password_token = token
                fp.save()

                forget_password_mail.delay(user_email, name, token)
                messages.info(request, 'An email has been sent to your registered email.')
                return redirect('forget-password')  
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'User does not exist')
                return redirect('forget-password')   

    except Exception as e:

        print("\nthe exception is comming from forget_password : ", e, "\n")
    
    return render(request, 'fp_email_form.html')
```

So, here I am trying to get the user first in user_obj from my CustomUser model and then I am trying to get the same user in the ForgetPassword model and store the token against that user. But I am getting the below exception

```
ForgetPassword matching query does not exist.
```

Please suggest or correcct me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a ForgetPassword object associated with the user object you are trying to fetch at,

`fp = ForgetPassword.objects.get(user = user_obj)` 
Instead, you should use `get_or_create`.

[reference link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

Comment: I actuallly tried that, the obeject is being created without storig the token and I am getting this exception " 'tuple' object has no attribute 'forget_password_token' "

Comment: The `get_or_create` returns two objects, In your case (fp_obj, created). And you have to assign token to fp_obj. Please read how it works, you will get it.

Comment: Okay, I now I got it we have to pass the forget_password_token in the function it self.

And just to clarify we can only use get() when the object exists right ? else we have to use get_or_create?